# Using offset to create a dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I currently have a column, which starts at B28 (The title) and from B29 Values.

[image]

I add data to the column using a macro, and calculate the mean and standard deviation of the profit figures. Since i add data, I can't just select for example B29:B10000 as it will skew any mean and standard deviation, as it will also take into account blank cells. Therefore, I need to create a range, which will update when data is added and will only range from the first to last numerical figure, no blank cells.

The current formula I use which does not work:

```
=OFFSET('Panel'!$B$28,1,0,COUNTA('Panel'!$B28:$B999)-1,1)
```

(also tried selecting the whole column $B:$B but did not work)

Is there any solution for this?

Cheers

Comment: I would probably update the formula in the VBA module based on the number of entries or with an `.end(xlup)` criteria on column A... Either that or take a look at INDIRECT feeding a count of Column A added to the row number from the title row

Comment: The problem you are encountering is that column B pre-populated with 0 so all these rows are being counted. The way to correct the formula would be to count the rows in column A.

Answer (score 1):

yes. Convert the range to table.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Use normal formula e.g. **from average(B2:B9)** to **average(tablename[Profit])**

***Before Year 8 is added***

[image]

***After Year 8 is added - auto update***

[image]